# Updating WebGL texture from color buffer during creation fails

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I have a WebGL texture,initially filled with pixels from image. Now I am trying to clear it with solid color from an array. Here is my function to create a texture2D:

```
function createGLTexture(gl, format,intFormat, w, h,wrapType, flip, genMipmaps, data)
{
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, flip);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,wrapType);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,wrapType);
  if (genMipmaps === true)
  {
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, intFormat, w, h);
  } else
  {
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, intFormat, w, h);
  }

  if (data != null) {
    gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, format, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  }

  if (genMipmaps === true) {
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  }

   return texture;
}
```

This is the code that initialized the texture with color:

```
  //img - image previously loaded
  var colorData = new Uint8Array(img.width * img.height * 3);
  for(var i = 0; i < colorData.length;i+=3)
  {
  colorData[i] = 0;
  colorData[i + 1] = 0;
  colorData[i + 2] = 255;
  } 
  var tex = createGLTexture(gl,gl.RGB,gl.RGB8,img.width,img.height,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,false,false,colorData);
```

Calling `createGLTexture` functions results in the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'texSubImage2D' on
> 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Overload resolution failed.at
> createGLTexture

I can's see anything I am doing wrong in terms of data/texture size. But what I tried was to update the texture with the color immediately after initialized it from an image source:

```
 function updateGLTexture(gl,texture, format,w,h, genMipmaps, data)
 {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,w,h, format, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    if (genMipmaps === true)
    {
      gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
 }
```

When I am updating the texture with a color using `updateGLTexture()` it works. I am getting the surface cleared to blue. Why? Why `texSubImage2D` doesn't allow update from color buffer upon texture creation? Is calling `updateGLTexture()` not the same as calling `texSubImage2D` after storage allocation with `texStorage2D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are encountering is hinting at the fact that you didn't provide the correct parameters to the `texSubImage2D` function. Some functions in WebGL/WebGL2 are ["overloaded"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), which in effect means that based on the amount and combination of parameter types you pass into the function, the parameters may get interpreted differently.

Judging from your error message, it seems you are using WebGL2. The WebGL2 standard defines [three overloads](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.7.6) for `texSubImage2D`:

```
undefined texSubImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, [AllowShared] ArrayBufferView srcData, unsigned long long srcOffset)
undefined texSubImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, TexImageSource source)
undefined texSubImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLintptr offset)
```

However, the code that is giving you the error is trying to use an overload that only exists in WebGL1 which was subsequently removed in WebGL2. The code you provided that works is using an overload supported by WebGL2 (the first in my list). If you changed your original code to include the correct function overload from your `updateGLTexture` function, it should work again.

Unfortunately, it seems like the older WebGL1 version of the API is displayed quite prominently on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D) without much clarification, so that may have lead to some confusion. It should be noted that the support for WebGL1 or WebGL2 [overloads listed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D#syntax) are exclusive, rather than inclusive -- that is, WebGL1 only supports the WebGL1 overloads, and WebGL2 only supports the WebGL2 overloads.

For others using WebGL1, if you do use the overload from this question it should be noted that the last parameter for that specific overload must be an image (e.g. `ImageData`), and not a `TypedArray` or `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: I am still confused. In both functions I use texSubImage2D() with no srcOffset param,So it is the second overload in both cases.

Comment: @MichaelIV Sorry, I didn't notice you were missing the last parameter. It is still the first overload, just that the lack of the last parameter means that the `srcOffset` (the offset into the array from which the data is read when uploading to the gpu) is zero. Also note how in your `createGLTexture` function, you didn't give the width/height, while you did in the `updateGLTexture`, which is why only the second one worked (only WebGL1 supports the overload without width/height). Hope this helps :)